# questions i tripped on in an interview

Tags: java

i was asked a few java interview questions which i had no idea how solve could use some answers

1. write a method which takes an int so the method would be

   public void somemethd(int i){}

   Now if i=1 then it should print true and if i=2 it should print false
   but you cannot use any conditional operators nor can you use if or switch
2. how do two threads pass data in between each other, like let lets say you start 2 threads and you want to make one thread make the other thread wait.
   he rephrased the question to make it simpler, what if i have a varible in 1 thread and i want to send it to another thread how to do that.
3. what if there is a non static method in base class and you make it a static method in derived class, would you get the same error as if u has a static method in base and u try to make it non static in derived class
4. what is the use of overloading other than same name for different method?
   (i guess i should have said constructor overloading but it just didnt come to me, is there anything else)
5. the syntax is not correct but u can jus assume everything is fine

   class base{

   show(){

   this.mymethod();
   }

   mymethod(){
   /...
   }
   }

   class derived extends base{

   ```
   show(){

   super.mymethod();
   }

   mymethod(){
   /...
   }
   }
   ```

now what happens when i do the following

a.

```
base b = new derived();

   b.show();
```

b.

```
derived d= new base();

   d.show();
```

c. what if there was no show method in base n i did

```
 base b = new derived();

   b.show();
```

d. what if there was no show method in base n i did

derived d= new base();

   d.show();

Comment: I only got as far as the first question - which is totally nonsensical. I hope your interviewer explained it really rather more clearly.

Comment: "write a method which takes an int and prints 1 if true and prints 0 if false" I guess.

Comment: Was this an interview for a Java position?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Presumably the first questions wants 'true' for 1 and 'false' for 0.

Comment: is it write a method which takes an int and prints true if 1 and prints false if not 1"

Comment: System.out.println(i%2 != 0);

Comment: I think they wanted you to know about bitwise operations for question 1. '1' would be represented as '.....01' in binary and '2' would be represented as '.....10'.  bitwise 'and' the value with '1' to find out if the number is '1' or '2'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution to the updated 1)

```
void printIsOne(int n) {
   System.out.println("?,true,false".split(",")[n]);
}
```

2) You cannot pass local variables between threads. However you can pass a value from one thread to another and have it wait for the value. IMHO: The simplest way is to use a BlockingQueue.

3) You get different error in both cases, but basically you cannot change one to the other in a derived class.

4) backward compatilibity. You may have code, e.g. loads of test code, which calls a method with one set of args however you want to change it in some way without changing the existing code.

5) just try it (hint: some combinations get a compiler error)

Comment: Thanks, I often build an array/list of String this way. Don't know if its better, just makes the list of items tighter without all the "," etc

Comment: i didnt really understand how if i start two threads, i can make 1 thread get another thread to wait.

Comment: With BlockingQueue, you add(value) on one thread, on the other thread, you do a take() to get that value. The second thread will wait for a value to be available. Its just one line of code on each thread and is thread safe. It couldn't be simpler. ;)

Comment: public void somemethod(int i) {

Answer (score 8):

> write a method which takes an int and
>   prints true if 1 and prints false if
>   true but u cant use if or swith or any
>   conditional operators

I'm guessing you mean true if 1 and false if 0, in which case you can do this:

```
void printValue(int value)
{
    String[] values = { "false", "true" };
    System.out.println(values[value]);
}
```